# Show fullscreen ad once every two time a button is clicked

Tags: ios, xcode, revmob

I'm using revmob to display ads in my app. I used to have it so that everytime the stop button for my timer was pressed, an ad would show. I want to make it so that it shows less. For example, the user press the button once, nothing happens. The second time, the ad shows up. So 1 out of 2 times, the ad shows up. 2 out of 4 times, the ad shows up, etc.

Code i'm using to launch the ad:

```
- (IBAction)Stop {
[timer invalidate];
if (self.fullscreen) [self.fullscreen showAd];
}
```

I just want a way to count how many time the stop button has been pressed and after every 2 times, show an ad =)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to track the number of times it has displayed. I've tried to keep the code understandable, so it is a little overkill.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int currentViews;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int maxViewCount;
```

Then in `viewDidLoad` (or equivalent)

```
self.currentViews = 0;
self.maxViewCount = 2; // show it every 2nd view
```

Then increment and check:

```
- (IBAction) Stop {
    [timer invalidate];
    self.currentViews++;

    if ((self.fullscreen) && (self.currentlViews == self.maxViewCount)) { 
         self.currentViews = 0; // reset the view count
         [self.fullscreen showAd];
    }
```